# Python initialize class with variables in init file and default constants file

Tags: python, oop

I have a class with a long list of variables (at least a dozen). In the module I first import a constants file which contains some helper methods and all of the default constants.

```
from myConstants import *

class SomeClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(var1=VAR1, ..., varN=VARN):
        super(SomeClass, self).init(var1, ...)
        self.varM = varM
```

**PROBLEM:** I would like to be able to specify a file when I initialize the class where the file contains a subset of the constants in `myConstants.py`. The variables not in the init file would be loaded from the defaults. Something like:

```
sc = SomeClass(initFile='/path/to/file')
```

My thought was to have something like

```
from myConstants import *
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

class SomeClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(var1=VAR1, ..., varN=VARN, initFile=''):
        if initFile: 
            parser = SafeConfigParser().read(initFile)
            var1 = parser('constants', 'var1') if parser('constants', 'var1') else VAR1
            var2 = parser('constants', 'var2') if parser('constants', 'var2') else VAR2
            ....
            varN = parser('constants', 'varN') if parser('constants', 'varN') else VARN
        else:
            var1 = VAR1
            ...
            varN = VARN

        super(SomeClass, self).init(var1, ...)
        self.varM = varM
```

**QUESTION:** Is this the best way to do this? If not, what is? Seems a little long winded. I'm also not married to ConfigParser.

Comment: tip: don't use "wildcard imports", like `from foo import *`, either explicitly do `from foo import bar1, bar2, bar3, ...` or alternatively `import foo` and do `foo.bar1, foo.bar2`

Comment: Can I ask why not? That file contains a lot of variables / methods and most are being used. The explicit import would be SUPER long. Plus anytime a new constant is added I would have to go in and change each module file.

Comment: So you should do the second of cowlicks's suggestions; just do `import foo`, then refer to them as `foo.bar1` etc - no need to change anything when you add new ones.

Comment: The idea behind this is to keep your namespace small and clear. You get a lot of names and can not be sure where they are defined. Is this variable with the name `length` from the myConstants module or defined locally? With `myConstants.length` you definetely know.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Any thoughts on my actual question? :)

Comment: @sal there is a canonical style guide for writing python code known as pep8. The section on imports is [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use two separate constructors, one that takes a file and another that takes explicit arguments.

```
class SomeClass(ParentClass):
    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, init_file):
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        parser.read(init_file)
        var1 = parser.get('constants', 'var1') if parser.has_option('constants', 'var1') else VAR1
        # likewise var2, ..., varN
        # This results in a call to cls.__init__
        return cls(var1, var2, ..., varN)

    def __init__(var1=VAR1, ..., varN=VARN, initFile=''):            
        var1 = VAR1
        ...
        varN = VARN

        super(SomeClass, self).init(var1, ...)
        self.varM = varM

x = SomeClass(1, 2, 3)
y = SomeClass.from_file(config_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Man, this ConfigParser clearly shows its age - 
it definettely should have a mapping interface - I had to poke a little
around to get a way to get its values - but this is a more suitable
code for you:

```
class SomeClass(ParentClass):
    options = {"var1": VAR1, "var2": VAR2, ...} 
    def __init__( initFile='', **kwargs):
        options = self.__class__.options.copy()
        if initFile: 
            parser = SafeConfigParser().read(initFile)
            for option_name in parser.options("constants"):
                if options_name in options:
                    options[option_name] = parser.get("constants", option_name)
        else:
            for key, value in kwargs:
                if key in options:
                    options[key] = value

        super(SomeClass, self).init(**options)
        self.varM = varM
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use configparser object and modify it to suit your needs using a dictionary of default values:

```
default_values = {
    "var1": "42",
    "var2": "23",
}

conf_parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
conf_parser.read(config_file)

for var, default_value in default_values.keys():
    if v not in conf_parser["DEFAULT"]:
        conf_parser["DEFAULT"][var] = default_value
```

This should overwrite all missing values in the configparser.
After that you can just pass along the configparser object and access all variables using `config_parser["DEFAULT"]["var1"]` and so on. This has the upside that all your variables are neatly bundled together and you only have one parameter for the constructor.

On the other hand this is a bit ugly and the config parser only knows how to work with strings, so maybe a dictionary would be better suited for this task.

I hope this helps.